# Why is VBA reading my ElseIf statement but not executing the code under it?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have some nested If and ElseIf statements.

The code runs through the if and elseif statements with the st value.

What the code should do is loop through the elseif statements with the first genr value, match the st, store the cap value (62 in this case), calculate the max value for that cap value, and then loop to the next genr value.

I've stepped through it to debug, and it does actually go the elseif line for genr = Q3. However, it skips the new cap value and completes the rest of the code with the old  cap value. cap is an integer

Is there something I'm missing?

```
st = "H" 'take st=H as an example, genr for it is Q1 and Q3

Gen = o.Cells(cell.Row, "G") 
        
G = Split(Gen, ",") 
        
For k = LBound(G) To UBound(G)

    If Left(Trim(G(k)), 1) = "Q" Then
    
    Genr = CStr(G(k))
           
       
    If St = "H" Then
        If Genr = "Q1" Or Genr = "Q2" Then
            cap = 62
        ElseIf Genr = "Q3" Then
            cap = 63
        End If
    ElseIf St = "Wh" Then
        If Genr = "Q1" Or Genr = "Q2" Or Genr = "Q3" Then
            cap = 65
        End If

' and so on for the rest of the st = "" loops
     .
     .
     .

End If

max = c.Cells(cap, "G").Value + max
    
End If 'endif of trim
    
Next k
```

Comment: not sure there is enough info to know what is happening here. So the cap value should be 63? Have you followed the rest of the code to make sure it doesn't get written over again later on? Also, `Select Case` is prob cleaner here. Or creating a 2d array mapping of Q# to cap

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code, executing it step by step to understand where it works different than expected?

Comment: All of that just to assign a row number\? There is prob an easier way to do this but not enough info to really know.

Comment: You use Trim() to check if the first letter is "G" but you don't use Trim() when assigning the value to `Genr`, so try fixing that.  If there are spaces your If will fail.

Comment: If it is stepping onto the ```ElseIf Genr = "Q3" Then``` but not assigning ```cap = 63``` make sure ```Genr``` is actually ```Q3```.

Comment: What is `st` actually set to? The first line of code sets it to whatever is stored in a variable called `H`, not the string "H".

Comment: @Applecore sorry this is a very long code so I tried to only include the key part of it that I'm struggling with. st picks up a string value in a cell next to a selected cell. no issues with vba picking it up, so I'm just saying its = to the value h as an example.

Comment: @FunThomas yes, it goes through everything (picks up the first genr value, grabs the cap value associated with it, calculates the max value, and then goes to the next genr value which is Q3, gets back to the else loops, goes to the first if, then to the cap value, then to elseif, but then skips the new cap value and goes to the endif line

Comment: The second value in the array is going to be the first one with a leading space if your split string looks like "Q1, Q3, Q4"

Comment: As @Applecore said you need the double quotes around the H. You need to rethink the logic of the code: You are testing if `Genr = "Q1", "Q2", "Q3"` after you have already established that it starts with a `"G"`. How is that going to work? Do you actually mean to say `If Left(Trim(G(k)), 1) = "Q" Then`?

Comment: @Super Symmetry yes I'm sorry I meant that it was = "G". I changed the letters as some of the references use the column "G" so I thought it would be easier to read here if I just simplified some of the names, sorry about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
'* st = "H" instead of st = H
st = "H" 'take st=H as an example, genr for it is Q1 and Q3

Gen = o.Cells(cell.Row, "G") 
        
G = Split(Gen, ",") 
        
For k = LBound(G) To UBound(G)
    
    '* Changed = "G" to = "Q"
    If Left(Trim(G(k)), 1) = "Q" Then
    
    '* Added the Trim here
    Genr = Trim(CStr(G(k)))
           
       
    If St = "H" Then
        If Genr = "Q1" Or Genr = "Q2" Then
            cap = 62
        ElseIf Genr = "Q3" Then
            cap = 63
        End If
    ElseIf St = "Wh" Then
        If Genr = "Q1" Or Genr = "Q2" Or Genr = "Q3" Then
            cap = 65
        End If

' and so on for the rest of the st = "" loops
     .
     .
     .

End If

max = c.Cells(cap, "G").Value + max
    
End If 'endif of trim
    
Next k
```

Please read comments starting with `'*`

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I accidentally left the =G in there, the only change I had to make was the ''' Genr = Trim(CStr(G(k)))''' line and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You use `Trim()` to check if the first letter is "G" but you don't use `Trim()` when assigning the value to `Genr`, so try fixing that. If there are spaces your `If` will fail.

```
G = Split(Gen, ",") 
        
For k = LBound(G) To UBound(G)

    Genr = Trim( CStr(G(k)) )
    If Left(Genr, 1) = "G" Then
```

Comment: sorry, should've mentioned this but it is picking up the next Genr when stepping through, hence why it's able to go to the elseif statement.

Comment: But if it's not executing `cap = 63` that suggested `Genr` is not `Q3`...

Comment: @las It doesn't matter what ```Genr``` is it will check every part of the ```If``` if it doesn't then go inside the ```elseif``` ```Genr``` is not ```Q3```